# Angular 2 test isolation (template errors)

Tags: angular, testing, angular-cli

I have an Angular (2.4.5) application created using angular-cli (1.0.0-beta.26) and I am experiencing testing difficulties. I have a simple component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-empty',
  templateUrl: './empty.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./empty.component.css']
})
export class EmptyComponent { }
```

(both .html and .css are empty files) and unit test:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { EmptyComponent } from './empty.component';

describe('EmptyComponent', () => {
  let component: EmptyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EmptyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ EmptyComponent ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EmptyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

When `npm run test` is started the test fails with error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'value' since it
isn't a known property of 'app-detail-section-item'.
```

That relates to some other component which is also being tested. What I don't understand is why this other component affects test of EmptyComponent? Is it because Webpack bundles tests together? I would expect the tests to be isolated. I can make the test pass using `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` but that does not seem right thing to do.

Comment: can you give us the full output from the console?

Comment: @MezoIstvan Please find it here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ymVhu1SZm0d3pPQUhOT3RhaEk/view?usp=sharing (it's too big to paste here).

Answer (score 0):

In the end the problem with the test isolation was caused by `beforeEach()` function defined out of `describe()` scope in some tests. That caused those `beforeEach()` to be run for all the tests in the suite and I was experiencing side effect described above.